# which neural network to use?

Tags: neural-networks, nnet

I have explored this site for the answer but could not find what i was looking for. My problem is i have data containing many variables (22) that are continuos and categorical and my output has two levels 1(present) or 0 (absent). My questions are:

1) What type of library, for a neural network model, would be best for this type of data (`nnet` or `neuralnet` in `r`)

2) I have been told that this is a regression problem not a classification, however since my output only has two levels why is this regression and not classification?

Answer (score 1):

Both packages `neuralnet` and `nnet` can be used for your task.

If you receive warnings on you are running regression but not classification, try to change the type for the response variable using function `factor`.

```
library(nnet)
library(mlbench)


set.seed(0)
d=mlbench.2dnormals(500)
plot(d)
d=data.frame(x1=d$x[,1],x2=d$x[,2],y=d$classes)

# nnet function from nnet package
fit1<-nnet(y~.,data=d,size=10)
fit1

# nnet from neuralnet package
library(neuralnet)
d$y=as.numeric(d$y)
fit2<-neuralnet(y~x1+x2,data=d,hidden=10)
fit2
```

Comment: Thank you, however when i convert my response variable into a factor in the neuralnet package i get an error message stating that i am using the wrong model for classification ?

Comment: @Martin hard for me to see what's happening with limited information here. But I will give you 2 examples on each package by revising answer.

Comment: Thank you for the example. This works fine for me and i can do both types of models from each package with no problem. however, when i try to cross validate this, under the caret package, i get the error message, "wrong model for classification", even when i convert the response variable to a factor. This is where my confusion comes from and why i ask the question, "is this is a classification or a regression problem", as it seems running the 'neuralnet' package with a factor as the response variable does not work?

Comment: @Martin that seems to be off topic for CV.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, this could be why i cannot find the answer to this problem anywhere.